# How do I update the URL after changing the hosting of a website?

Tags: uri

Our website recently changed hosts. After updating the named servers the home page shows but all links in the page take you to 404 error.  The new host advises that the URL links need to be refreshed.

Comment: Did you cleared the caches?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities when this happens. The first is to make sure that you still have an .htaccess file, as moving between hosts sometimes doesn't include the hidden files.

If you do have it, depending on the server, the Symlinks may need to be changed. For instance my Ubuntu server needs the .htaccess file to be changed to this in order for it to work

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks // Commented out
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

The next possibility is that the DNS propagation hasn't finished yet. It can take up to 72 hours with some hosts before everything is fully refreshed and pointing the right location.